Too long spacing between special structures and memoir headings
If we use memoir in article mode, there will be an unusually long space between constructions such as itemize or flushleft and subsequent chapter*’s. Using just \documentclass{memoir} and \section* instead of chapter* removes the problem, and so does using \documentclass{article}. What is going on here?
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Hello World}

Hello world

\chapter*{Hello}

\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\item Hello
\end{itemize}

\chapter*{Nej}

\begin{flushleft}
I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello.
\end{flushleft}

\chapter*{Hello}

Hi

\end{document}



It is \vspace vs \addvspace, need to catch a bus, details later.

The article chapterstyle in memoir sets the space above chapter using vspace whereas @startsection (section and friends) uses add space, which give different results when spaces combine (space below env and space above chapter). Redef a single macro and they look the same

@daleif Redefine which single command?

Not at pc. Look in the memoir source, the definition of the article chapterstyle, there should be one prominent macro that uses vspace, redefine it to use addvspace

Looking in the sources we see that the article chapter style uses
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}

for the space above the \chapter command in article mode. But \section and friends uses \addvspace which combines differently with other vertial spaces.
You can use the example below to get a more simular spacing.
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\addvspace{\beforechapskip}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Hello World}

Hello world

\chapter*{Hello}

\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\item Hello
\end{itemize}

\chapter*{Nej}

\begin{flushleft}
I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello.
\end{flushleft}

\chapter*{Hello}

Hi

\end{document}

